# How to bind a List<KeyValuePair> with the Value being a List of "some" object as DataSource to a (SyncFusion) DropDownList?

Tags: c#, dictionary, dropdown, key-value, syncfusion

I'm trying to bind a List as DataSource to my (SyncFusion) DropDownList, my original DataSource is a Dictionary that looks like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<Kpi>> KpiGroupDropDown { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, List<Kpi>>();
```

[image]

As u can see this Dictionary<string, List> contains 3 items, item 1[index 0] has the key "Propulsion" and this has a reference to a List which contains 3 objects.

Because the SyncFusion DropDownList only accepts ICollection Types I have converted my Dictionary into a List like this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, List<Kpi>>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<Kpi>>>();
```

[image]

Now I initialized my (SyncFusion) DropDownList:

```
<SfDropDownList  TValue="KeyValuePair<string, List<Kpi>>"
                 TItem="KeyValuePair<string, List<Kpi>>"
                 DataSource="@list"
                 @bind-Value="@SelectedGroupChartType"
                 CssClass="custom-dropdown"
                 Width="100px">
<DropDownListEvents TValue="KeyValuePair<string, List<Kpi>>" ValueChange="@OnChartTypeSelected" />
<DropDownListFieldSettings Text="list.Key" />
</SfDropDownList>
```

However the items that I've filled in at : TValue, TItem , DropDownListEvent TValue and DropDownListFieldSettings Text are incorrect(I think). I'm also not sure what to fill in on these properties, can anybody help me figure this out?

I also have added a ValueChange(OnChange method) to this DropDownList in the DropDownListEvents that is called "OnChartTypeSelected", the code of that method is as follows:

```
private void OnChartTypeSelected(Syncfusion.Blazor.DropDowns.ChangeEventArgs<KeyValuePair<string, List<Kpi>>> args)
{
    var test= args;
}
```

What I would like to achieve:

The DropDownList displays the Key's of each item in the KeyValuePair and I would like to pass the Value's(List of the selected item into the "Args" of my OnChange method.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

currently, syncfusion did not have support to render the TValue as complex data type in the Dropdownlist component. We have already considered this complex scenario and logged this requirement as a feature request at our end. We will implement this feature in any of our upcoming releases.  We appreciate your patience.